# Verifying that a letter is in a python string - Why I got this result?

Tags: python

I am new to programming, and am learning on Python 3.4.  I am working on an exercise to determine if a user defined letter is a vowel or consonant.

My original if statement looked as follows:

```
letter = input('Enter a letter')

if letter == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'u':
    print('your letter is a vowel')
else:
print ('your letter is a consonant')
```

this returned that my letter was a vowel every time.

I have since learned the answer was to  have an if statement that looks as follows:

```
if letter == 'a' or letter == 'i' or .......
```

My question is why did my original if statement return that it was a vowel every time, and not give me an error?

My though process is that it is verifying that it is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any non-zeroish value evaluates to True in a condition.  Also, comparison operators (`==` in this case) have higher priority than logical operators (`or`,`and`,`not`).  (Details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)
So python interpreted your if statement as:

```
if (letter == 'a') or ('e') or ('i') or ('u'):
```

Since 'e' is not zero or zero-like, that part of the if was true, so your expression was true.

An easier approach than your working solution is:

```
if letter in 'aeiou':
```

Which checks if letter is a character in the string.

Comment: Thanks!  Understood.